# Sweepstake generator

Tags: python-3.x

im a newbie and am tearing my hair out over this looping problem.  I want to randomly assign a country to a list of people for a sweepstake competition.  Once a country has been assigned then it should be no longer available to be assigned in further iterations of the loop.  The loop should go through the whole list of people (which is shorter than the country list).  yes i know the code could be simpler but this is just the point at which i gave up.  Please advise!

```
import random
filez = open ('C:/Users/Andy/Desktop/countrys.txt', 'r')
countries = filez.readlines()

filez2 = open ('C:/Users/Andy/Desktop/names.txt', 'r' )
people = filez2.readlines()

def chop (x):    #gets rid of wierd added bits
    for i in range(0, len(x)):
        x[i] = x[i] [:-1]
    return x

chop(countries)
chop(people)

def assign (y):
    used = []
    for person in range(0, len(y)):
        num = random.randint(0, len(countries))    
        if num not in used:
            print (people[person] + " gets " + countries[num])
            used.append(num)
        else:
            num = random.randint(0, len(countries))
            print (people[person] + " gets " + countries[num])
            used.append(num)


assign(people)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution would be:

```
random.shuffle(countries)
assignments = list(zip(people, countries))
```

Which will give you a list of `(person, country)` tuples.

Comment: Brilliant and very simple, thanks!  Didnt know about random.shuffle, list or zip .  Need to keep doing tutorials i guess!